# How to un-pad a string/number with zeros

Tags: python, padding

I know that to pad a string you do something like:

```
>>> n = '6'
>>> print n.zfill(3)
>>> '006
```

and a number:

```
>>> n = 6
>>> print '%03d' % n
>>> 006
>>> print "{0:03d}".format(6)  # python >= 2.6
>>> 006
>>> print("{0:03d}".format(6))  # python 3
>>> 006
```

My question is: Is there a way to undo/un/de-pad a string and number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can simply do:

```
your_str.lstrip('0')
```

### Examples

```
>>> '00003'.lstrip('0')
'3'

>>> '0234782394000'.lstrip('0')
'234782394000'
```

### Note

`lstrip` does **not** get rid of zeroes at the end of the string:

```
>>> '00100'.lstrip('0')
'100'
```

Comment: will this also work for a number?

Comment: @Renier, Well a number would never have leading zeroes in the first place. However, if you mean a number string, then yes.

Comment: I will once I can... wait 1 more minute `:)`

Comment: @Renier, Thank you and good luck with your project. :)